# Using NServiceBus in CQRS

Tags: c#, nservicebus, cqrs

I am trying to implement a CQRS model for our website. The main idea is that each service(module) will be called via json web service which will in turn fire off update commands. Now my CQRS project is a just  a simple class library written in c# . When i have to publish the event at the end I need the Bus object, which I am not getting(i.e. the bus object is null) because I am not running nservice bus as an external application. Is there a way in which i can initialize the bus without running the application from an external line command.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: So, you are trying to host NSB in what?  IIS, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: Well till now the plan is to refer this CQRS project's dll into a web service project and host that web service on IIS. The NserviceBus is referred inside the CQRS class library project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to host NServiceBus in IIS, you will need to manually configure it.  Instructions for this are [here](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/852419-hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process).

NServiceBus can be hosted in any process, however, there can be reasons why hosting in IIS is not the [best idea in some scenarios](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/).  It is usually best to send a command to a generic host that is hosting your NServiceBus handlers.  This is usually deployed as a windows service and handles a particular type of message (command).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that , i am  trying to create  the bus in my class library project rather than in my web service application. I am trying to instantiate the bus but it gives me the error 'MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig' configuration section is missing and could not find backup configuration section 'MsmqTransportConfig' in order to locate the error queue', now i checked in my app.config and the above mentioned tags are there. Sorry if i wasn't clear earlier about creating the bus in the class library project rather than the web service.

Comment: Check out this article for more help:
http://particular.net/articles/using-nservicebus-in-a-asp.net-web-application

Comment: The section you're missing is one single line in the <configsections> section, and it's this line:
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />

Comment: @sa1986 You cannot use an app.config for a class library by itself.  You always need a host process.  The host process contains a configuration file.  For an IIS hosted process (ASP.NET or Web Service), you use a Web.config file in the root directory.  For a WinForms, Console or WPF app, you use an App.Config file in the root directory.

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt in my app.config i have those sections. I am trying to follow the example which you have given the link for, only thing different is that i am trying to implement it for a wcf service, and gives me the following error: NServiceBus has detected that you're running in a web context but have passed in a null synchronizer. Please pass in a reference to a System.Web.UI.Page or a System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.
Parameter name: synchronizer

Comment: @DavinTryon I think you are right i won't be able to do this in a class library projetc , i am trying to now do this in a wcf project but getting this error as soon as the Bus. send is called :NServiceBus has detected that you're running in a web context but have passed in a null synchronizer. Please pass in a reference to a System.Web.UI.Page or a System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.
Parameter name: synchronizer